# How to get unread email info using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
Pop3Client pop3Client;
if (Session["Pop3Client"] == null)
{
    pop3Client = new Pop3Client();
    pop3Client.Connect(txtMailServer.Text, int.Parse(txtPort.Text), chkSSL.Checked);
    pop3Client.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    Session["Pop3Client"] = pop3Client;
}
else
{
    pop3Client = (Pop3Client)Session["Pop3Client"];
}
int count = pop3Client.GetMessageCount();
DataTable dtMessages = new DataTable();
dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber");
dtMessages.Columns.Add("From");
dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject");
dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent");
int counter = 0;
for (int i = count; i >=1 ; i--)
{
Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(count);
Message msg = pop3Client.GetMessage(count);
    dtMessages.Rows.Add();
    dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["MessageNumber"] = count;
    dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["Subject"] = message.Headers.Subject;
    dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["DateSent"] = message.Headers.DateSent;
    counter++;
    if (counter > 5)
    {
        break;
    }
}
gvEmails.DataSource = dtMessages;
gvEmails.DataBind();
```

Can anyone tell me how to get an unread email  info using asp.net web application? I only know how to get all emails.and i want to listen new emails from this application,please any one help to me??

and also i need to download the attachment????any one tell me how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use IMAP protocol.
I think these links will be handy [first](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/205509/How-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-asp-net.aspx#answer1) and [second](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/asp-net/17/10172236/how-to-retrieve-mails-from-gmail.aspx)